# Line integral over a scalar field

Tags: vector-analysis

given $f(x,y,z)=z e^{-xy}$ and curve $r(t)=(t,t^2,e^{-t})$. How can i find line integral of this scalar field over given curve?

Comment: Any bounds suggested for t?

Comment: Yes...t is ranging from 0 to 1